# I'm getting an access violation when using the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm getting access violation when trying call a simple dll using LoadLibrary:

```
Access violation at address 03454D62 in module 'test_dll.dll'. Write of address 00429D24.
```

Code for Test.DLL:

```
library Test_DLL;

uses
  dialogs;

{$R *.res}


procedure Test(source, dest : string);stdcall;
begin
  messageDlg('Source: ' + source + chr(13) + 'Dest: ' + dest, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
end;

Exports
  Test;

begin
end.
```

Calling the function using this:

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TCheckMessage = procedure (test1, test2 : string);
var
  CheckMessage : TCheckMessage;
  DLLHandle : Cardinal;

const
  DLL_FILE = 'test_dll.dll';
  DLL_PROC = 'Test';
begin
  dllHandle := LoadLibrary(DLL_FILE) ;
   if dllHandle <> 0 then
   begin
     @CheckMessage := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, DLL_PROC) ;
     if Assigned (CheckMessage) then
       CheckMessage('test1', 'test2')  //call the function
     else
       ShowMessage('"' + DLL_PROC + '" function not found') ;
     FreeLibrary(dllHandle) ;
   end
   else
     ShowMessage(DLL_FILE + ' not found / not loaded') ;
end;
```

This seems like an easy thing to do, but I must be missing something. I did notice that the DLL procedure calls seem to be case-sensitive. It does appear the that procedure call is happening. DLLHandle and @CheckMessage are getting populated and the code runs, but throws an access violation as soon as:

```
CheckMessage('test1', 'test2')
```

is called.

Comment: I rolled back the previous edit. It is not acceptable to edit code in a question other than to improve formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to pass `string` across a DLL boundary. You might get away with it if you use a shared memory manager (as described in the comment that you deleted from the top of the library unit). And if you use the exact same version of Delphi to compile both DLL and executable.

Instead you should use interop safe types. For instance `PAnsiChar`, `PWideChar` or `WideString`.

Your other problem is a mismatch of signatures. The exported function uses `stdcall` calling convention. But when you import it, you use the default `register` calling convention. Clearly the calling convention needs to match.

Comment: While this is true, I believe the actual cause of the error is that it's missing `stdcall` on the calling signature.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you. I did not look past the most obvious (to me) problem

Comment: 'TCheckMessage = procedure (test1, test2 : string);stdcall' fixed the issue....Thanks for the help....

Comment: @SMM No, that did not really fix the issue. You have to stop passing private Delphi types like `string` across a DLL boundary. You may get away with it here, but in the long run this ends badly.

Comment: @SMM Do you plan on using this DLL from other software which was written in another language? Or even another version of Delphi? If so, it will not work with a `string` as David explains. Exporting Delphi `String` types from a DLL is much like putting Diesel gasoline in a car that takes regular unleaded.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, but at least a petrol car will fail spectacularly and mostly immediately in that situation, alerting you straight away to the fact that something has gone wrong.  Passing a delphi string, however, can temporarily provide the illusion of functioning until horrible bugs emerge at some point in the future (leaving one in a terrible debugging predicament).

Comment: @J... Technically Diesel *could* (not will) work in certain cars, but super sluggishly, and will most definitely destroy the engine. That was the idea of the analogy.

Comment: @Jerry: No, diesel will *not* work in a car designed to run on gasoline, and the failure is extremely rapid (typically within the first few hundred yards from the gas station). I speak from experience: when I was a teenager, I worked in a gas station where the fueling company accidentally pumped diesel fuel into our unleaded regular tank, and we paid quite a few thousands to reimburse for towing, pumping out the car fuel tanks, replacing fuel filters, etc. before we became aware of the issue and shut down the pumps. (The fuel supply company ended up footing the bill eventually.)